# cellTap on small tablets not working (Tabulator)

Tags: tabulator

I am using version 5.4 of tabulator in my tables I have the function of editing the cell, when I try to modify the cell through my tablet the keyboard opens and closes immediately and at the same time the focus of the cell and the drop-down menu are lost. There are the options to modify that cell. I have reviewed the website in version 5.4 and in the cell editing examples exactly the same thing happens, the browser I am using is Chrome version 116.0.5845.188 (Official Build)

I tried to edit a cell by selecting a value from the dropdown but I don't have the option to do so since it opens and closes immediately

Comment: New issue open  in ->https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/4305